# selected page link issue

Tags: html, css

Im trying to create a better way of letting the user know what page they are on by telling my global navigation to stay one colour. What I mean is if the user is on the home page I want the word "Home" to stay blue for example so that they know thats the page they are currently looking at.

Im not sure if i've explained it very well but if you take a look at the jsfiddle bellow it'll make more sense.

http://jsfiddle.net/4kUp3/

Comment: I think you should include code here too so you don't just direct out.

Comment: How did you want to do this? JavaScript? PHP? Other?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to just hard code the style into each page to highlight the item, you could use jquery to grab the element that links to the current page and change it's style

```
$('a[href="'+window.location.href+'"]').parent().addClass('selected_link');
```

Answer (score 0):

**You could compare each link in the menu with the current page URL.** With jQuery:

```
$('#site_nav li a').each(function(){
    if($(this).attr('href') === window.location.href) {
        $(this).parent().addClass('selected_link');  // apply style to li
    }    
});
```

- [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/4kUp3/1/)

Answer (score 0):

You have it setup correctly, the order on your CSS is just messed up a bit.

Change

```
.selected_link li a:link
```

to

```
.selected_link a:link
```

and HOME will be blue.